# R using special characters

Tags: r

I have a column of strings (and NAs) in a dataset whose values look like:

```
"85min"  "1hr 19min"  "98min"  NA  "119min"  "105min"  NA  "1hr 30min"
```

I'm trying to change all of the values to numerics (in minutes), so that the values look like:

```
85  79  98  NA  119  105  NA  90
```

I tried to do it by pieces, first removing the "min," then removing the "hr," then changing "1" to "60," and then changing the middle spaces to plus signs, giving me:

```
"85"  "60+19"  "98"  NA  "119"  "105"  NA  "60+30"
```

I was hoping that by applying as.numeric, I would get the ones with "+" signs to turn into formulas, but instead they just resulted in NAs.

Is there any shorthand way of doing this kind of conversion? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Related: [From timespan for example “15 min” or “2 sec” to “00:15:00” or “00:00:02” using existing R function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204878/from-timespan-for-example-15-min-or-2-sec-to-001500-or-000002-usin) and [Convert age entered as 'X Weeks, Y Days, Z hours' in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32744743/convert-age-entered-as-x-weeks-y-days-z-hours-in-r?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,  you need `parse` and `eval`

```
strings = c("85",  "60+19",  "98",  NA,  "119",  "105",  NA,  "60+30")
sapply(parse(text=strings), eval)
[1]  85  79  98  NA 119 105  NA  90
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much. I only wish I had asked days ago...